# foreach in PHP - how to transfer the values in a variable?

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox, foreach

so the problem is, I have a HTML form with checkboxes as an input-option.
I want to save all the selected options as a string(!) in one variable.

I'm pretty sure the solution is a foreach-loop, but mine doesn't work. It only returns the last selected value.

How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>category:<br/>
     one <input type="checkbox" name ="ber[]" value="one"><br/>
     two <input type="checkbox" name ="ber[]" value="two"><br/>
     thr <input type="checkbox" name ="ber[]" value="three"><br/>
     fou <input type="checkbox" name ="ber[]" value="four"><br/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
foreach ($_POST['ber'] as $value) {
$ber = "$value. ', '"
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['category']` should be `$_POST['ber']` no?

Comment: The name will be `$_POST['ber']` not `$_POST['category']` and you are overwriting the $ber variable each time round the loop

Comment: Judging by this `$ber = "$value. ', '"` ... it looks like its about to be stuffed into a mysql query :(

Comment: @IncredibleHat that is right. you don't seem very happy about that. could you explain why? I would really appreciate to learn more about it. since I'm quite unexperienced :)

Comment: @Nat_ CSVs should not be stored in a column. 1 value per column. You also should not pass user input to a SQL query. Queries should be parameterized. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: What @user3783243 said ;)

Comment: yes, I see. But let's pretend there was only one value to be added via user-input; wouldn't it help to treat the input with htmlspecialchars() or so?

Comment: No, `htmlspecialchars` is for outputting to a browser, not for SQL. (It also does nothing to single quotes by default) Also injections can be done a number of ways. It is best to parameterize and let the driver escape everything than guessing how an injection might look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called "implode an array":

```
$ber = implode(',', $_POST['ber']);
echo $ber;
// or simply
echo implode(',', $_POST['ber']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate.

```
$ber = ''
foreach ($_POST['ber'] as $value) {
    $ber .= "$value. ', '"
}
```

With your current approach `$ber =` overwrites the previous value.

A better solution though is `implode`.

Comment: And you need to change `$_POST['category']` which does not exist to `$_POST['ber']`

Answer (score 2):

You will get the selected checkboxes value in POST array

```
<?php $_POST['ber']; ?>
```

Now If you want to assign this array to variable with comma separated

```
<?php $beer_value = implode(",", $_POST['ber']); ?>
```

Comment: Mine is a pint please, but the OP's is `$_POST['ber']`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your foreach loop with below foreach loop. You are getting `ber` in `POST` not `category`. So you need to change `$_POST['ber']` from `$_POST['category']`.

```
$ber = '';
foreach ($_POST['ber'] as $value) {
    $ber .= "$value. ', '"
}
```